# Schema-validation: missing column in table for subclass

Tags: hibernate, kotlin

I'm working on a Spring Boot program and am running into an issue with JPA that I can't figure out.

I have three classes; `User`, `Content`, and `Demo`. Demo is a subclass of Content, and Content has an author (User). Below are simplified versions of the classes:

**User.kt**

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class User() {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = 0

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "author", orphanRemoval = true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    var demos: MutableSet<Demo> = HashSet()

    ...
}
```

**Content.kt**

```kotlin
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
abstract class Content() {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    open var id: Long? = null

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    open var author: User? = null
}
```

**Demo.kt**

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "demo")
open class Demo : Content() {}
```

When I start the program, it runs into an error with the `demos` field in `User`:

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [author_id] in table [demo]

I had expected it to use the `author_id` column for `Content`, which is present in the database and setup as a foreign key to the users table. However, this is apparently not the case.

How can I ensure that the `author` field in `Content` is used so that I don't have to duplicate it in sub classes?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to replace this `var demos: MutableSet<Demo>` by `var demos: MutableSet<Content>`

Comment: That works but then it also includes other sub classes of `Content` and I'm looking only for `Demo`

Comment: So, you should add just additional filtering. for example by jpql